# One splash screen for all display sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

So, the question:
Is there any way to use a simple .xib or something like it, to have a splash screen with just a solid background extending the full width and height of the screen with a single, centered image?

I'm just learning iOS development and Objective-C.
I'm trying to find a simpler way of creating a splash screen for an app without using the traditional loading images.

Why?
In android development, I can use a fragment as a splash screen and place a single image at the center on a colored background. This will scale for ANY screen size, in ANY orientation.

In iOS development, they want me to create multiple image files for every orientation and screen size. This is not very scalable. If the logo or design changes, every one of these files has to be recreated and added again to the app.

Comment: Create a script in illustrator to export your image in the multiple resolutions. This is trivial to do.

Comment: This is what we do in our office too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that the launch image Apple requires you to include is not for the purpose of being a splash screen. It is there to make the transition from the launchpad into the splash screen smooth. Yeah, it doesn't scale well, but it's just one image - you can handle it.

I don't know how to do it using auto layouts, but the old school way would be to place a `UIImageView` in the centre of the view set its `autoresizingMask` property to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`. In Interface Builder it would look like this:
[image: using autoresizingMask in IB]

Comment: So can I place an empty view with the autoresizing height and width with a RGB background then place the image in the center? How do I set the attributes for an image to be placed in the center on just a solid background. This is close to what I want but not quite. (I honestly hate Apple's approach to layouts and views. I come from a web development background and prefer raw code access to element attributes and methods.)

Comment: It won't take you long to get your head around using Interface Builder, and I promise you that once you do you'll be disgusted by Android/web development style. You can still access the raw properties in code, but you can set it all up visually and it's a treat!

Comment: So the question still remains though, can I set up a single autoresizing view with a solid background and have a single image in the center? How would I center that image if the screen size changes?

Comment: Look at my screenshot. That's how you set it up in IB. Or use the code I mentioned: `imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

Comment: Ok. I think i'm not quite getting it across. The logo needs to NOT scale, but it needs to be centered. That's the part I don't quite understand. Thanks for your patience on this. Still pretty new to iOS...

Comment: `imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;` - that will keep it centred without resizing it.